# Delete values in VBA with hidden Cells

Tags: excel, vba, delete-row

I am trying to delete all "0" values from a table in excel. I have the following code written but it returns that Method 'Range of object'_Worksheet' failed. What do I need to do to fix this?

```
Sub Macro()

Dim ws As Worksheet          
''Set reference
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Compressed Schedule results")

''Apply Filter
    ws.Range("A2:B2").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="0"
 lrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Row
''Delete the Rows
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ws.Range("A2:lrow").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True


ws.ShowAllData



End Sub
```

Comment: What line returns the error?

Comment: Variables don't go inside quotes: `ws.Range("A2:A" & lrow)`.

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad The row with A2:lrow in it, the one that is supposed to delete

Comment: @BigBen after I fixed this I get the error "Delete method of Range class failed"

Comment: Side note - do you want to delete or just clear contents? Do you want to delete the entire row or just the cells in column A?

Comment: @BigBen I want to completely delete that row

Comment: Then you need `.EntireRow.Delete`.

Comment: @BigBen I still get the delete method of range class failed, could you elaborate on what this means?

Comment: Maybe `Debug.Print ws.Range("A2:A" & lrow).Address` - what's the result?

Comment: @BigBen Object required

Comment: What's the value of `lrow` at that point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @BigBen noted, you are referencing a range with a variable incorrectly.  I also removed the `SpecialCells` when setting the last row:

```
Sub Macro()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lRow As Long
''Set reference
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Compressed Schedule results")
lRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row  
''Apply Filter  
ws.Range("A2:B2").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="0"
''Delete the Rows
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ws.Range("A2:A" & lRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
ws.ShowAllData
End Sub
```